# Why are shared files mapped 4 times in a process

Tags: linux, procfs

I was trying to understand the `maps` in the `/proc` file system in Linux. I observed that every shared file was mapped 4 times, with different offsets and permissions. I concluded that these must be the different sections in the ELF and hence are mapped differently (`.text`, `.data`, `.rodata`, etc).

But what was surprising is that two of the mappings always had the same offset in the file. Consider the example -

```
7fb8eebd6000-7fb8eebe0000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 3285700 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
7fb8eebe0000-7fb8eeddf000 ---p 0000a000 08:06 3285700 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
7fb8eeddf000-7fb8eede0000 r--p 00009000 08:06 3285700 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
7fb8eede0000-7fb8eede1000 rw-p 0000a000 08:06 3285700 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
```

The 2nd and the 4th entry is mapped at the same offset in the file with different permissions. 
Upon running `objdump --headers` on the mentioned `.so` file, file offset `0xa000` seems to the `.got.plt` section.

```
24 .got.plt      00000160  000000000020a000  000000000020a000  0000a000  2**3
                 CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

Can some one throw light on why it is mapped twice?

I know about the PLT table that it is patched the first time the function is visited, and hence might need a write permission, but why another mapping without any read/write permissions?

**Edit:** I checked a few other shared library mappings and it is not the `.got.plt` section that is mapped twice. But there is always one section that is mapped twice and the double mapping always has the `---p` permissions.

Comment: I expect it's mapped with copy-on-write. So the second mapping is the copy.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that it must be a CoW, but the virtual addresses for both the entries are different. Why have the first one at all? It doesn't even have read permissions on it.

Comment: Haven't read it yet, but [this](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html) may be helpful.

Comment: @Barmar read that just a few minutes ago. Doesn't mention anything about the double mappings. Actually I checked a few other libraries. It is not the `.got.plt` that is double mapped always. Some times it is some other section. But there is always one section double mapped and always it is with `---p`. permissions. I will edit the question and add this.

Comment: You might get a response by posting this on [unix.se].